# Show that every positive integer has a unique representation in the form $50k+l$...?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

with -24 $\lt l \le$ 25.

Then I need to conclude that all final 2-digit numbers of the decimal expansion of squares are to be found among those of $0^2, 1^2, 2^2,...., 25^2$.

I'm thinking that I could maybe rewrite the division theorem proof for this but I don't know how/what to do with that. Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably split your questions into two separate threads.

Comment: Are you sure it's $-24 < l \leq 25$? Because that would mean $0 < l + 24 \leq 49$. How would you write $-24$? For example, $-24 = 50(0) +  (-24) = 50(-1) + 26$, I suspect you need 'weak' inequalities on both ends, or different endpoints.

Comment: I copied it exactly as is from my textbook. Also to your comment: it's only claiming this is possible for positive integers

Comment: OK; then how would you write $50(1) + (-24) = 26$? I'm just saying it's not a complete set of residues modulo $50$; you won't be able to prove it, as it stands. Something about the possible values for $l$ needs to change; it needs to be $1$ 'wider'.

Comment: oh you're right! It must be a mistake in the textbook

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $b>1$, every positive integer $x$ can be expressed as 
$$
\frac{x}{b} =  = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor + \frac{r}{b}  \\ r \in \Bbb{Z}: 0 \leq r < b\
$$
where the first term is the greatest integer not exceeding $\frac{x}{b}$ and $r$ is the "remainder" when doing that division. We can write this as 
$$x = b \left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor + r$$

Now consider the case of even $b$: $b = 2n$. 
$$x = 2n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2n} \right\rfloor + r$$
and either $0 \leq r \leq n$ or $n < r < 2n$.  Consider the first of those choices: and let integer $k$ be defined by 
$$
k \equiv  \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2n} \right\rfloor 
$$ 
Then $x = k b + r$ with $0 \leq r \leq n = \frac{b}{2}$ which satisfies the statement (which is the particularcase of $b = 50$).

Now consider the other possibility $n < r < 2n$ and let integer $k$ be defined by
$$
k \equiv  \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2n} \right\rfloor + 1
$$ 
Then 
$$
x = 2n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2n} \right\rfloor + r = 2n (k-1) + (r-n) + n\\
x = 2n k - (2n-r) = bk - (2n-r)
$$
Finally, when $n < r < 2n$,
$-n < 2n-r < 0$ so this expression also satisfies the statement (it gives the negative values of $\ell$).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at the first part, not sure if it actually proves it though. Feedback appreciated!

by the division theorem, for all integers b, there exits unique q, r such that $b=aq+r, \space 0\le r \lt a$

letting $a=50$, we see that the inequality can be rewritten as $-24\lt r-23 \le 25$ and $b-23 = 50q +(r-23)$. Let $l=r-23, \space c=b-23$. Then $c=50q+l, \space -24\lt l \le 25$ as required.